# Get value of anchor tag in jquery which generate dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I have a functionality where i have `anchor` tags that generate dynamically. 
Now i have a next button which onclick would generate another anchor tag For eg : `8` if the last digit is `7`.

For Eg:

```
<a id="a1" href="#">4</a>
<a id="a2" href="#">5</a>
<a id="a3" href="#">6</a>
```

I know by using the below code i can get the anchor value

```
 $('#a1').click(function () {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
```

On click of `next` button i append another:

```
<a id="a3" href="#">7</a>
```

But i have more than 100 anchor tags getting generated(Consider a paginator i keep clicking next button). I cant hardcode the functions for 100 anchor tags. Is there any approach or generic method that i can use to get values of anchor tag?

Comment: Select by tag, or give them all a common class. Also, you'll need to use a delegated event handler if you're appending the element dynamically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Attribute Starts With Selector [name^=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector,

I would suggest to have common `class` and select elements based on `class-selector`

```js
$('[id^="a"]').click(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="a1" href="#">4</a>
<a id="a2" href="#">5</a>
<a id="a3" href="#">6</a>
```

**Using `class-selector`:**

```js
$('.a-elem').click(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="a1" class="a-elem" href="#">4</a>
<a id="a2" class="a-elem" href="#">5</a>
<a id="a3" class="a-elem" href="#">6</a>
```

**Note:** You might want to consider [**`Event delegation`**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) if elements are being appended `dynamically`

Answer (score 6):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when **generating elements dynamically**.

You should assign a common class the use [Class Selector (“.class”)](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

*HTML*

```
<a class="anchorLink" href="#">6</a>
```

*Script*

```
$(document).on('click', "a.anchorLink", function(){
    alert($(this).text())
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container for better performace.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate through all `<a>`, it's easy:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
         alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: do you really need `each()`?

Comment: Also with this approach, we lose specificity....There could be many `a` elements on which OP may not want events associated...

Comment: Yeah, this example iterate through all the anchors, sorry if someone is disturbed

Comment: You say it's not mandatory. But [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/) directly discourages using `each()` in these cases: "most jQuery methods that return a jQuery object also loop through the set of elements in the jQuery collection — a process known as implicit iteration. When this occurs, it is often unnecessary to explicitly iterate with the .each() method"

Comment: `"often unnecessary"` is similar to `"not mandatory"`. I know all of this, I tell sorry again.

Comment: Personal preferences? Tell me a post on stackoverflow where there's not "_personal preferences_" on the answers. Every developer have got different criteria for the same tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this.

```
<a class="yourclass" id="a1" href="#">4</a>
<a class="yourclass" id="a2" href="#">5</a>
<a class="yourclass" id="a3" href="#">6</a>

    $('.yourclass').click(function () {
            alert($(this).text());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a id="a1" href="#" value="4">4</a>
```

script:

var text=$(this).val()